# PAWN to C++ global variable

Tags: c++

How do i write it in c++ ??

```
// in PAWN ( Procedural Language )
enum e_player_data
{
    id, // Integer
    username[24] // string 
};
new PlayerData[50][e_player_data];
/*
    so i can access it like PlayerData[1][id] = 1; or PlayerData[1][username] = "Firstname_Lastname";
*/
```

Can someone code it to c++ for me?

Comment: [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tobi303 wrote in the comment, you can use a std::map to accomplish this.

```
struct e_player_data
{
    int id,
    std::string username
};
std::map<int,e_player_data> PlayerData;

PlayerData[1].id = 1;
PlayerData[2].username = "Firstname_Lastname";
```

Comment: why a `struct` and not simply `std::map<int,std::string>` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `std::map`:

```
typedef std::map<int,std::string> Player;

Player p;
// add a player:
int id = 0;
p[id] = "Max Power";
```